# Aren't がる and たがる the same thing?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, definitions, jlpt

In my JLPT practise book, it has two different entries, one to explain `がる` and one to explaining `たがる`. It offeres these example sentences to differentiate them:

> うちの子{こ}は新{あたら}しいものを見{み}ると、すぐほしがる。
>
> うちの子{こ}は甘{あま}いものを見{み}ると、すぐ食{た}べたがる。

I think they both mean to behave in a way that expresses the feeling described. So, `ほしがる` means to not only hope for, but to act like you hope for it, and as a result, everyone who sees you will know you are hoping. Something like that...　I don't have a pithy way of explaining `がる`.

So, if my definition is right, it seems both sentences are explaining essentially the same thing, and the only difference is one is attached to a verb, and the other is attached to a... um... something else. Whatever the grammatical category of `ほしい` is.

I'm confused about why the book is going out of its way to explain them separately.

Is there a difference in definition between `がる` and `たがる` beyond just how they fit into a sentence grammatically?

Comment: がる attaches to i-adjectives and words which conjugate like i-adjectives.  ほしい → ほしがる, 食べたい → 食べたがる, 嬉しい → 嬉しがる, and so on.

Comment: @DaveMG I'd advise you to get the grammar dictionaries by Seiichi Makino and Michio Tsutsui. They are really handy for learning sentence patterns.

Comment: So the た has nothing to do with garu; tabetai goes to tabeta-. It's exactly like hoshikunai (don't want) and tabetakunai (don't want to eat) where we do not think about "kunai" versus "takunai".

Comment: I think it would have been interesting to know how your JLPT book explained each separate entry.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Expanding on @TsuyoshiIto's comment above, `がる` basically turns an イ-adjective (or "words which conjugate like" them, as he states) into a verb.  Essentially means "acting this way" or "behaving in such a way":

> - 寒【さむ】がる　→　To be cold (さむがり: a person who is always cold -- like me); "acting that you are cold"
> - 怖【こわ】がる　→　To be afraid of something; "behaving such that you are afraid"

As a logical following of this, `たがる` is really just the 〜たい form of a verb (which conjugates like an イ-adjective) plus `がる`

> - 食べたがる　→　("Acting like") Wanting to eat
> - 行きたがる　→　("Acting like") Wanting to go
> - 見たがる　→　("Behaving like") Wanting to see/watch

Since `〜たい` cannot be used to directly state a 3rd party's desires (unless followed by something like `〜と思っている` or `〜と言う`), you must use `〜たがる`.

> ×　となりのひとは新しいテレビを買いたい。
>   ○　となりのひとは新しいテレビを買いたいと言った。
>   ○　となりのひとは新しいテレビを買いたがっている。
>   ○　となりのひとは新しいテレビを買いたいようだ。

I think the confusion in your examples is that you just happen to be using `食べたい` (want to eat) and `ほしい` (generic "wants").

So there's really no need to think that there are two separate grammar patterns here.  The pattern is really just `がる`.  It just depends on whether you're attaching it to a regular イ-adjective or to a `〜たい` イ-adjective.

Comment: となりのひとは新しいテレビを買いたいようだ sounds fine to me.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto To me, it seems like tai, hoshii, etc., would all be acceptable with pretty much any grammatical form that makes it so the statement is not a direct expression of fact. So anything from: ようだ、みたい、そうだ、らしい、だろう、と思う、はず、わけ、etc. seem like they should all be acceptable. Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @NathanEllenfield: I think that your comment is about right, but と思う seems a little different from the other endings.  More precisely, it seems unacceptable to me to use ～たいと思う when expressing the speaker’s guess at a third person’s desire.