# What is って doing in this sentence?

Tags: translation, verbs, meaning, conjugations, i-adjectives

From Noir, Episode 2 (anime).

I don't get what the って is doing in this sentence. For context, the father came home early from work. He quickly answers his wife in the first sentence then in the second sentence is asking his son this:

> そうか。そうだアンリ、欲しがってたゲーム、明日パパと買いに行こうか？

Comment: You know I didn't even know there was a verb for `to want`. I thought you had to use `Xが欲しいです。` to express that. Hence, my confusion. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause, section "Using relative verb clauses as adjectives" explains it nicely.

Comment: @herby This is, IMO, different. It's an i-adjective that's been made into a verb (by dropping `i` and adding `garu`). Because I didn't realize that I couldn't tell what was going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `～て` form of `ほしがる` which means "to want".

> ほしがってたゲーム　→　The game that I'd been wanting

xref [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3839/78).

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know there was such a thing in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

> hosigar-te i-ta (gemination)→ hosigatteita (contraction)→ hosigatteta
>       want-gerund progressive-past