# How would you use the 'と思います' form to say what others are thinking?

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrases

'と思います' is usually used when saying what you think/your assumptions, that much I know, but is it possible to alter it so that you can say what others are thinking? For an example, how would you say, 'Mary thinks the stars are beautiful'?

Comment: Just precise the subject : "Hoshi ga kirei da to _Mary ga_ omotte imasu"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Japanese is a language in which expressing ***others'*** feelings, thoughts, desires, etc. is done considerably more discreetly than expressing one's own.

It is 100% natural to say:

> 「私{わたし}は、星{ほし}はきれいだと思{おも}います。」

but it is ***not*** natural at all for a native speaker to say:

> 「田中{たなか}さんは、星はきれいだと**思います**。」

even if Tanaka has directly told the speaker that he (Tanaka) thinks that the stars are beautiful.

「思います」 is reserved for the speaker/writer; You cannot use it when the subject of the verb is another person.  The same principle is applicable to other words like 「ほしい」、「したい」、「怖{こわ}い」, etc.

One could say instead:

> 「田中さんは、星はきれいだと**思っています**。」

If Tanaka has directly told you so.   And you might say:

> 「田中さんは、星はきれいだと**思っているようです**。」

if the information has been obtained via a third person.

All this might sound strange to you, but you will need to get used to the idea.  As a Japanese-speaker, I felt very strange, too, when encountering a sentence like "**My father thinks I am crazy**." in my English textbook a few years ago in junior high school and so did just about all of my classmates because that sentence made very little sense to us.

You might want to read:

[When to use 欲しがる instead of 欲しい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/when-to-use-%e6%ac%b2%e3%81%97%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b-instead-of-%e6%ac%b2%e3%81%97%e3%81%84)

[Translation of 泳ぎたがっている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/translation-of-%e6%b3%b3%e3%81%8e%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b)

Comment: is Garu used only for  ほしい　and たい? 思ってがってるis incorrect?

Comment: just correcting myself, I actually know that you can use garu with many things, but can I use it with 思う?

Comment: I would recommend that you ask this question separately as a new post.

Comment: ん？ なんかサラっとサバ読んだ？　a few decades ago の間違いじ（（殴

Comment: What is it about 田中さんは、星はきれいだと思っています that makes it any more appropriate than saying 田中さんは、星はきれいだと思います? I understand why the later doesn't work (and you explained it well).  I don't understand why 思っています is acceptable.  It seems to me equally presumptuous.