# Which one is correct for this sentence 欲しよう or 欲しがる

Tags: grammar

If I want to say " I think my grandma wants me to stay over tonight as well."

Are any of these ok?
祖母は 今日も 私に泊まって欲しよう。
祖母は 今日も 私に泊まって欲しがる。<-- but i'm not sure how I should add "I think(と思う)" into this sentence

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/how-would-you-use-the-%e3%81%a8%e6%80%9d%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-form-to-say-what-others-are-thinking/56908#56908

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts are incorrect. 欲しよう is ungrammatical in any situation. Please check the grammar rule of よう in your textbook.

Here are some correct ways to say this:

> 1. 祖母は今日も私に泊まって欲し**そ**うだ。
> 2. 祖母は今日も私に泊まって欲し**い**ようだ。
> 3. 祖母は今日も私に泊まって欲しがっている。
> 4. 祖母は今日も私に泊まって欲しいと思っている。

These are semantically similar, but Sentences 1 and 2 mean "*Looks like* grandma wants me to..." whereas Sentence 3 and 4 directly describe her wish.

See:

- [Difference between そうです、 ようです and らしいです.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16312/5010)
- [When to use 欲しがる instead of 欲しい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2524/5010)