# Why does と思います point to "you"?

Tags: translation

There is a sentence on IMABI:

> 太ったのはなぜだと思いますか

Which translates to:

> Why do you think it is you got fat?

Why is it `you think`? If I were to translate it, it would be `I really wonder why you got fat?` (`really` comes from `だ`, which as I think has emphasis purposes after `なぜ`)

Where have I got it wrong? Or can this sentence be translated either way?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/how-would-you-use-the-%e3%81%a8%e6%80%9d%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-form-to-say-what-others-are-thinking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a very simplified explanation: because the か makes it a question.

Comment: And here I thought there is some greater magic happens : ) Is it safe to assume that whenever sentence is a question, it always points to `you`, if subject isn't clearly specified?

Comment: @Nexen Context would generally make it clear, but I believe most unspecified questions would indeed be second person.

Comment: The main confusion I had with this was `だ` which is assertive and it's rude to say others thought with certainity. It was also pointed in related question - https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56908/9205 . Is `なぜ` (and maybe others: who/what/which) a special word and therefore it's okay to use `だ`?

Comment: @Nexen Using だ *right at the end of a sentence* sounds assertive and rude. With と思う you *have* to use だ after a noun or na-adjective. (Also だね, だよ, and the like don't quite sound as aggressive as だ) Also, while you generally use 思っている for other people, because this is a question, it's perfectly to use 思う.