# How to say "they liked it" in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice

A mangaka that I like replied me in my native language, and when I showed this to my parents they liked it. I want to say that to this mangaka, but I don't know how to say that in a natural form.

I thinked in these phrases

> 昨日の返信を両親に見せて、気に入りました。
> 昨日の返信を両親に見せて、好きになりました。
> 昨日の返信を両親に見せて、いいだと思いました。

But I think that it means something like "I liked to show yesterday reply to my parents". How can I say "I showed yesterday reply to my parents and they liked it" in a natural and correctly form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation attempts will **never** mean "to like to show" or "to want to show". Something like this is expressed using a completely different construction in Japanese. Do you know about the [-tai form](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/tai-form/)?

However, your attempts have several other mistakes.

- Adjectives like いい don't take だ, so いいだと思う is ungrammatical.
- 好きになる means something becomes one's (permanent) favorite rather than liking something for a moment. If you used 好きになる, it would sound like your parents became (permanent) fans of the mangaka.
- You cannot directly use 気に入る, 思う and so on with a third-person subject. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56897/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2524/5010). You need to add ようでした or みたいでした.
- It's better to use 見せ[たら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/5010) instead of 見せて because the subjects of the two clauses (見せる and 気に入る/好きになる/いいと思う) are different.

Therefore, my suggestion is one of the following:

- 昨日の返信を両親に見せたら、気に入ったようでした。
- 昨日の返信を両親に見せたら、いいと思っているようでした。

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot :)

Comment: Would it be right 気に入ったと言いました?

Comment: @Mauro It sounds unnatural. You should say 気に入ったと言っていました or 気に入ったと言っています. Here's a [related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14764/5010).