# Ambiguity in sentences with a noun qualified by an adjective with が particle

Tags: grammar, particle-が, relative-clauses

I was wondering if there is any ambiguity with sentences that have adjectives qualifying a noun, especially regarding the が particle.

> 1. 僕が好きな人

Can this sentences have an ambiguous double meaning of "The person that I like" and "The person that likes me"?

> 2. 僕が食べたい魚

Can this mean either "fish I want to eat" or "fish that wants to eat me"?

to make the meaning of this sentence clearer would

> 3. 僕を食べたい魚-

ONLY mean "fish that want to eat me" as the only interpretation?

Is there a go-to interpretation for qualifications like this or does one have to identify exclusively via context unless there are further details provided?

For example,  more detailed, clear-cut sentences

> 4. 僕が好きなところ

This sentence would ONLY mean "The place that I like/My Favorite place"

> 5.　野菜を食べるのが好きな人

In this sentence the only interpretation could be "People that like eating vegetables"

Comment: yes, it could mean both, it depends on the context. for example 2, there must be a context around it. yes for 3-4-5

Comment: For 3,4,5, yes as in those have just one interpretation?

Comment: only 1 interpretation. sorry for short answer, someone with more time may explain better.

Comment: This is not for learners, but if you feel like staring into the abyss, see [頭が赤い魚を食べた猫](http://togetter.com/li/567493), which can be interpreted in five ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.) [僕]{ぼく}が[好]{す}きな[人]{ひと}
>
> Can this sentences have an ambiguous double meaning of "The person that I like" and "The person that likes me"?

First, that is not a sentence; It is only a noun phrase (or a relative clause).  "The person that I like." is not a sentence in English, either.

The answer is affirmative.  **It can mean both**, but to mean "The person that likes me.", it is more natural to say 「僕**のこと**が好きな人」.

> 2.) 僕が[食]{た}べたい[魚]{さかな}
>
> Can this mean either "fish I want to eat" or "fish that wants to eat me"?

Strictly speaking, **no**.  It can only mean "the fish that I want to eat".

In Japanese, we DO NOT say 「～～たい」 to talk about a third party's desire (in this case, the fish).  We say 「食べたがっている」.　This is a common mistake among J-learners.

「僕（のこと）を食べたがっている魚」 = "The fish that wants to eat me"

See here for details: [Aren't がる and たがる the same thing?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/arent-%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b-the-same-thing)

> to make the meaning of this sentence clearer would
>
> 3.)僕を食べたい魚-
>
> ONLY mean "fish that want to eat me" as the only interpretation?

It is missing 「たがる」 as I mentioned above.  You need to use it to talk about the fish' desire.

> Is there a go to interpretation for qualifications like this or does one have to identify exclusively via context unless there are further details provided?

Depends on the phrase.  As I stated, 「僕が食べたい魚」 can only mean "the fish I want to eat" ***with or without*** further context, but the phrase would be ambiguous if one did not know about たい vs. たがる.

Context is important as Japanese is a most contextual language, but your own knowledge of the grammar and such is equally important.

Comment: 僕が食べたい魚 for "fish that want to eat me" is not entirely impossible in narratives though it's still uncommon. I personally mind excessive use of たがる.

Comment: you are giving wrong advices... for 2. strictly speaking YES, it can mean both, I mean grammatically(of course it makes no sense, a fish eating a human). Also maybe you might have seen grammar book that say you have to use たがる, but we actually use this kind of sentence (with たい) all the time ! example : ビールが飲みたい人, 真実が知りたいあなた... Actually japanese just use たい more often than たがる in conversation language

Comment: *I mean grammatically(of course it makes no sense, a fish eating a human)* I like that "fish eating a human" is the part that you had the biggest issue with. I can think of a few fish that do/can eat humans. :)