# が in subordinate clauses

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, subordinate-clauses, ambiguous-relative-clauses

Since you can't use は in subordinate clauses, it looks to me like が is forced to take on both roles, so how would we distinguish them? For example, if we have the sentence

> 僕が好きな動物

how do we distinguish between "animal that I like" and "animal that likes me"? Since it's が, I think that if we treated that clause like a sentence on its own it would definitely mean "I am liked" since が would directly link 僕 to だ, but I've seen sentences like

> 彼が好きな寿司

translated as "sushi that he likes", so either my assumption about が in a full clause is wrong or the way it works changes somewhat.

So far I've assumed that you can use clarifying nouns like 方 or こと, but I'm pretty sure that that won't happen in every usage case, if I'm even right about that.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use contrastive は in subordinate clauses.

Comment: But wouldn't this usage actually be thematic は? In 僕が好きな動物, I'm trying to find a way to clarify whether 僕 is thematic (for "animals I like") or if it's the regular usage of が linking 僕 to な/だ ("animal that likes me").

Comment: Right, I'm just pointing out that "you can't use は in subordinate clauses" isn't strictly correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

僕が好きな動物 actually can mean both, *the animal that I like* and *the animal that likes me*. But to mean the former it often becomes **[僕の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)**好きな動物, and to mean the latter it often becomes **[僕のこと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/5010)が**好きな動物 or **[僕を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)**好きな動物. In reality, you wouldn't run into such ambiguous phrases frequently.

But when you do encounter phrases like 僕が好きな動物, its interpretation purely depends on the context and your common sense. I am a native speaker of Japanese, and recently [posted a wrong interpretation of a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29565/5010) due to this ambiguity. (There was not enough context, and the sentence could make sense either way.)

Of course, 彼が好きな寿司 almost certainly means *sushi that he likes*, and 寿司が好きな人 almost certainly means *person who likes sushi* (unless you're talking about personificated Mr. Sushi).

In this case, if there were no context at all, I feel 僕が好きな動物 is likely to be taken as *the animal I like*, and 動物が好きな僕 is likely to be taken as *I, who like animals*. Maybe it's simply because talking about 僕's preference is more common in conversations.

Comment: Ha!  I love the bit about _"personificated Mr. Sushi"_ -- very funny image, and definitely a possibility, considering some of the wacky advertisements I've seen.