# Why does は change the entire sentence?

Tags: は-and-が

> 魚**は**好きな人。
>   Fishes like people
>
> 魚**が**好きな人。
>   Person that likes fish

Although I know the definition of both sentences it is very confusing to me, why が works and は doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean it changes the sentence? Did google translate tell you that?

Comment: I found this very useful for my own understanding: http://nihonshock.com/2010/02/particles-the-difference-between-wa-and-ga/

Comment: Frankly, neither of those sentence fragments make much sense to me. They might make sense if they weren't fragments. I am but a learner though -- perhaps natives have a different view.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30172/5010

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that you have wrongly understood these sentences.

There are two possible interpretations of 魚は好きな人。:

1. The fish is a person who I like.
2. A person that only likes fish.

To mean "Fishes like people", it should be 魚は人が好き。

Interpretation 1 doesn't really make sense, so 魚は好きな人。 is supposed to mean "Person that only likes fish".

Now the difference between 魚は好きな人 and 魚が好きな人 is not so big. Here は introduces a contrast between fish and all the others.