# Why is 文学**の**好きな人 ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, particles

When saying

> 文学の好きな人はいますか？

I was corrected to

> 文学が好きな人はいますか？

Why aren't both possibilities correct? I thought that ga can always be replaced by no in phrases that are used attributively.

Answer (score 4):

> 文学の好きな人はいますか？

I think this sentence is okay. [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/) has a number of similar examples, 歌の好きな人, マージャンの好きな人, 仕事の好きな人, お茶の好きな人, ...

After all, you can use が, の and even を interchangeably:

> - 文学が好きな人はいますか？
> - 文学の好きな人はいますか？
> - 文学を好きな人はいますか？

I personally prefer が or を here, but I expect people have different preference.

---

However, you have to pay a special attention when a noun representing a person comes in place of 文学.

> 太郎の好きな人は誰ですか？

For some reason, this sentence almost always mean "Who is the person Taro likes?", not "Who is the person who likes Taro?"

- 太郎が好きな人: **ambiguous.** the person Taro likes / the person who likes Taro
- 太郎のことが好きな人: the person who likes Taro
- 太郎のことを好きな人: the person who likes Taro
- 太郎の好きな人: the person Taro likes (!)
- 太郎を好きな人: the person who likes Taro

Well, there can be exceptions; 子どもの好きな保育士を探しています is usually taken as "I'm looking for a nurse who likes children". But almost all examples of Aの好きな人 found on BCCWJ, where A refers to a person, mean "the person A likes". Please don't ask me why...

Related:

- [が in subordinate clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30171/5010)
- [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)