# How does 好き work in relative clauses?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I'm trying to say something like "I want to make friends with people who like x" but I can't figure out how to say it. I think 「ｘが好きな友達を作りたい」but that doesn't seem quite right. Thanks.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30171/5010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「ｘが好{す}きな友達{ともだち}を作{つく}りたい。」

is a well-formed sentence with nothing incorrect or unnatural about it.  You could also say:

> 「ｘが好きな人{ひと}**と**友達**に**なりたい.」

Finally, it is also correct and common among us native speakers to say:

> 「[Noun] + 好{ず}きな人」　Note 「好き」 is read 「**ず**き」 here.

If you inserted a 「の」 or 「が」 between the noun and 「好きな」, then you pronounce the 「好き」 as 「**す**き」.