# A question about 受け身 in 連体形

Tags: grammar, ambiguous-relative-clauses

I saw this paragraph in news

> 19日、殺人未遂の疑いで逮捕された、仙台市内に住む 大学生 佐々木楓容疑者24歳。**刺した相手**は、44歳年上の交際相手の男性でした

I know 刺した相手 refers to the person who was stabbed. But I don’t know why the sentence uses 刺した instead of 刺された? As my understanding, the victim is the person who received the action, so you should use 受け身 form。

The below is two examples show how I understand 受け身.

1. 刺した男性 means the men who stabbed
2. 刺された男性 means the men who was stabbed

What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: There is no passive voice. Read 刺した相手 not as "the person who was stabbed" but as "the person who she stabbed". Related: [Ambiguity when describing with verbs, e.g. 酒を飲ませる人](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/79905/5010). And by 連用形, did you mean *relative clause* (or 連**体**節 in Japanese)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the meaning, both are about the 68-year-old man being stabbed.

The reason for using `刺した相手` is that the suspect`佐々木楓`has been introduced earlier, the subject of this sentence is the victim `男性`. The complete sentence should be `(容疑者が)刺した相手は、44歳年上の交際相手の男性でした`

However, if using `された`, the subject is usually omitted (regardless of whether it is yourself). And the complete sentence would be `(44歳年上の交際相手の男性は)容疑者に刺された` This can cause a duplication, as she has already been introduced

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure where there's a mistake that would prevent it from being updated as my answer or score.
If you need further clarification, please let me know. Thank you~

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is make it clear to OP that 刺した男性 can mean two things ("the man who stabbed (someone)" and "the man who (she) stabbed"). OP is clearly unaware of the latter interpretation. Before understanding this point, I doubt if OP can understand `刺した相手`.