# Desire form verbs (~たい), is there a polite form?

Tags: conjugations, honorifics, politeness

I was just curious if there is a way to make the ~たい form polite?
for example

```
戦いたい - Want to fight
```

I was thinking possibly using the honorific form instead of the masu form might be acceptable?

```
お戦いになりたい
```

Comment: ex.ご参戦なさりたい。A polite form of 知りたい is お知りになりたい? It sounds like 'to want to become the waist'. :) A verb word can change.

Comment: I got it.
I misunderstood, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the *honorific* form, rather than the simple *polite* form (which can be achieved by just adding です after 戦いたい).

お戦いになりたい sounds odd in most cases, because ～たい itself is usually for a desire *of your own*. Honorific expressions are for someone higher than you.

- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3844/5010
- [Can たい and たがる be used for a 1st/2nd/3rd person's desire?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23860/5010)

The natural honorific version would be 「将軍は戦いたがっていらっしゃる」「将軍は戦いたがっておいでだ」 etc. You can still use plain たい before other certain honorific expressions: 「将軍は戦いたいと考えていらっしゃる」, 「将軍は戦いたいと仰っている」.

As you can see in the second link above, there are cases where ～たい can be used for 3rd party's desire. For example I think 「将軍がお戦いになりたい理由が分かりません」 (="I don't understand the reason why General wants to fight") is not incorrect, although I still feel this is slightly awkward.

Comment: I was aiming for the simple polite form, thank you

Comment: A quick question on the subject
If I wanted to use the polite negative form should I say

戦いたいではありません or 戦いたくないです

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question... 戦いたいです and 戦いたくないです are the correct ones.

Comment: How about 「戦いたくありません」？

Answer (score 2):

My thought is as follows:
There are two types of paradigm.
たい is a adjective form that shows a state of a subjective will.
たがる is a verb form that shows a state from an objective viewpoint.

```
 私は戦いたいです。　　　　　　　I want to fight.
 あなたは戦いたがっています。　　You want to fight.

 私は戦いたくありません。　　　　I don't want to fight.
 あなたは戦いたがっていません。　You don't want to fight.

 私は戦いたいですか。　　　　　　(impossible sentence)
 あなたは戦いたいですか。　　　　Do you want to fight?
 彼は戦いたがっていますか。　　　Does he want to fight?
```

Therefore, 
because to ask directly other person's will is rude as the honorific form, I think たい is rarely used.

Comment: What makes "私は戦いたいですか。" an impossible sentence? Wouldn't it just be "Do I want to fight?" (as either a rhetorical question or as a bit of introspection)?

Comment: If your question is not joke, I answer you that is a little strange. In that case, perhaps I think that it is usually to say "私は戦いたいのだろうか".
I guess that "want to" in English and "したい" in Japanese are a little different.